# MySQL: Unknown column 'price_USD' in 'field list' - Update operation - correct query (it runs on phpMyAdmin)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

On an update query under Codeigniter framework, I got this error:

> Query error: Unknown column 'price_USD' in 'field list' - Invalid query: UPDATE `offers_prices_history` SET `price` = '37', `price_per_unit_of_active_ingredient` = 0.061666666666667, `unit_of_measure` = 'GBP / mg', `currencies_id` = '23', `price_USD` = 46.93339, `price_per_unit_of_active_ingredient_USD` = 0.078222316666667, `last_modified` = '2019-06-11 18:44:38'
>   WHERE `id` = '21'

If I copy and paste the entire query in phpmyadmin and run it, it works properly.

Here the DUMP of the used table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `offers_prices_history` (
      `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `offers_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `price` float NOT NULL,
      `price_per_unit_of_active_ingredient` float UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `price_USD` float DEFAULT NULL,
      `price_per_unit_of_active_ingredient_USD` float DEFAULT NULL,
      `unit_of_measure` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `currencies_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `creation` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `last_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    --
    -- Dump dei dati per la tabella `offers_prices_history`
    --

    INSERT INTO `offers_prices_history` (`id`, `offers_id`, `price`, `price_per_unit_of_active_ingredient`, `price_USD`, `price_per_unit_of_active_ingredient_USD`, `unit_of_measure`, `currencies_id`, `creation`, `last_modified`) VALUES
    (6, 16, 25, 0.0416667, NULL, NULL, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 11:26:15', '2019-06-11 11:26:15'),
    (7, 16, 26, 0.0433333, NULL, NULL, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 11:28:03', '2019-06-11 11:28:03'),
    (8, 16, 27, 0.045, NULL, NULL, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 11:28:46', '2019-06-11 11:28:46'),
    (9, 16, 28, 0.0466667, NULL, NULL, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 11:37:58', '2019-06-11 11:37:58'),
    (10, 16, 29, 0.0483333, NULL, NULL, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 11:45:53', '2019-06-11 11:45:53'),
    (11, 16, 30, 0.05, NULL, NULL, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 11:52:10', '2019-06-11 11:52:10'),
    (12, 16, 31, 0.0516667, NULL, NULL, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 11:53:16', '2019-06-11 11:53:16'),
    (13, 16, 32, 0.0533333, 40.591, 0.0676517, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 15:42:19', '2019-06-11 15:42:19'),
    (14, 16, 32, 0.0533333, 40.591, 0.0676517, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 15:44:17', '2019-06-11 15:44:17'),
    (15, 16, 32, 0.0533333, 40.591, 0.0676517, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 15:45:12', '2019-06-11 15:45:12'),
    (16, 16, 33, 0.055, 41.8595, 0.0697659, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 15:56:07', '2019-06-11 15:56:07'),
    (17, 16, 34, 0.0566667, 43.128, 0.07188, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 16:33:30', '2019-06-11 16:33:30'),
    (18, 16, 33, 0.055, 41.8595, 0.0697659, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 17:30:50', '2019-06-11 17:30:50'),
    (19, 16, 33, 0.055, 41.8595, 0.0697659, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 17:54:22', '2019-06-11 17:54:22'),
    (20, 16, 35, 0.0583333, 44.3965, 0.0739941, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 18:15:37', '2019-06-11 18:28:04'),
    (21, 16, 36, 0.06, 45.6649, 0.0761082, 'GBP / mg', 23, '2019-06-11 18:33:47', '2019-06-11 18:33:47');

    --
    -- Indici per le tabelle scaricate
    --

    --
    -- Indici per le tabelle `offers_prices_history`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `offers_prices_history`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      ADD KEY `ref_currency_id_idx` (`currencies_id`),
      ADD KEY `offers_prices_history_to_vendors_offers_idx` (`offers_id`);

    --
    -- AUTO_INCREMENT per le tabelle scaricate
    --

    --
    -- AUTO_INCREMENT per la tabella `offers_prices_history`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `offers_prices_history`
      MODIFY `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=22;

    --
    -- Limiti per le tabelle scaricate
    --

    --
    -- Limiti per la tabella `offers_prices_history`
    --
    ALTER TABLE `offers_prices_history`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `offers_prices_history_to_vendors_offers_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`offers_id`) REFERENCES `phar263d_PharmaComparisonDB`.`vendors_offers` (`id`);
    COMMIT;

    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

The function that performs the update simply use an associative array

```
function update($id, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update($this->table_name, $data);
}
```

and the array is populated as stated in the error message. I cannot understand what attempt to do since the error shows a correct query, the column that gives an error is existing. I searched for similar posts, read a lot with the same title, but not found similar trouble that I can summarize in this way

- update operation
- not existing column error for an existing column
- column names correctly quoted in the query string
- the query shown in the error message runs correctly when copied and pasted in phpMyAdmin

Comment: try var_dump your variables that you receive in your function and make sure you are receiving the data correctly

Comment: check the table, and make sure that field is there (double check). then if it is, check to make sure `$this->table_name` references `offers_prices_history`... maybe put an `echo $this->table_name` in the function. those are really the only two issues i can think of. that or you are connected to the wrong db.

Comment: @Jelly Beam, the query is printed in the error log, so the error that the system detects is in that query. If the data was not correctly received, how could the system create and print that query that runs correctly in phpMyAdmin? I copied and past the error log query in phpMyAdmin, not vice-versa. Anyway I try yo use var_dump.   And let you know here.

Comment: @fede72bari suggest also trying what Alex suggested, also please show us what $this->table_name gives you.

Comment: @Alex, thank you I will double check all the global variables in my environment.

Comment: fixed! The most stupid mistake, you both were right. After the last mercurial update, I had a rollback on variables definition from another developer; I couldn't imagine that the DB variable was different than the one I was using. Thank you and sorry to have wasted time for a so stupid mistake.

Comment: Nice you found it, maybe its time to install some kind of version control?

Comment: ^_^, in this case, the problem was that we are using mercurial, we modified both the same section of code. Among many conflicts, we didn't see we both modified that variable name. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

in set price='37' try to this SET price=37.

Comment: Shouldn't matter. In MySQL, numbers can be quoted without issue

Comment: oh thats right, check the controllers and paramaters $data send to model. maybe thats where the problem.

Comment: Also, OP figured out the problem [21 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557298/mysql-unknown-column-price-usd-in-field-list-update-operation-correct-q/56574392?noredirect=1#comment99696228_56557298) and it wasn't due to quoting